# Cross-Origin Request Blocked Laravel

Tags: laravel, cross-domain, laravel-middleware

I have Laravel 5.5 application and I want to avoid Cross-Origin Request Blocked error. I was trying to install barryvdh/laravel-cors package but it is not compatible with Laravel 5.5

```
barryvdh/laravel-cors v2.0.0 requires illuminate/contracts ^5.6|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/contracts[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37...etc
```

Is there another solution I could use? Maybe a native solution or write my own middleware for Laravel 5.5?

Comment: You could use version 0.11.0 for Laravel < 5.5, see [here](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/tree/0.11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `v1.0.6`, it's compatible with Laravel 5.5

https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-cors#v1.0.6

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting Class cors does not exist", after adding 'cors' to my middleware

Comment: Have you installed it per the docs? https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Comment: yes of course. I then added 'cors' to the list of my middlewares in the API

Comment: What's the stacktrace?

Comment: \framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(752): ReflectionClass->__construct('cors')",

Comment: in my API, i did this 'middleware' => ['cors', 'lang'], adding cors there, is it correct?

Comment: What's the full stacktrace?

Comment: I can't really post it because of the comment limit

Comment: The middleware should have `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class` not `'cors'`, but can't really tell without the full stacktrace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214724/discussion-between-marmahan-and-joundill).